# Including a string into another string in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation, strcat

How do I "include" a string into another string in C ?

Here is an example :

```
string1 = "www.google";
string2 = "http://"+string1+".com";
```

I'm having difficulties with strcat().

Thanks

Comment: `sprintf` might do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `snprintf` and its feature to return the size it would need if it had the space available:

```
const char *string1 = "www.google";
char *string2;
size_t length;

length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "http://%s.com", string1);
if (length < 0) {
    // Handle error.
} else {
    string2 = malloc(length + 1);
    snprintf(string2, length + 1, "http://%s.com", string1);
}
```

Slightly different variant which avoids having the format string two times:

```
const char *string1 = "www.google";
const char *format = "http://%s.com";
char *string2;
size_t length;

length = snprintf(NULL, 0, format, string1);
if (length < 0) {
    // Handle error.
} else {
    string2 = malloc(length + 1);
    snprintf(string2, length + 1, format, string1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'm having difficulties with strcat()

Then try sprintf:

```
char str[] = "www.google";
char dest[100];

snprintf(dest, sizeof(dest), "http://%s.com", str);
```

> *7.19.6.5-3*
>
> The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have
>   been written had n been sufﬁciently large, not counting the
>   terminating null character.

Comment: And be aware that this results in a potential buffer overflow if you don't check the length of `str` first!

Comment: `snprintf` can tell you how much space it would need, which makes it easy to allocate exactly the amount of memory needed instead of using a static buffer.

Comment: @DarkDust That's right, you just have to pass it 0 as the size.

Comment: @DarkDust [The Microsoft C Runtime Library version of snprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93(v=vs.80).aspx) doesn't return the required buffer size, but returns -1 to signal failure (ditto for very old versions of glibc), so sadly it's not portable.

Comment: @GameZelda That's unfortunate but good to know. I edited the question to make it completely clear that the "could have written" behavior is required by the standard.

Comment: @GameZelda: Well, the behavior I cited is required by C99 §7.19.6.5(3). I guess this is why MS named their version `_snprintf` instead.